# No suggestions when mining in Business intelligent studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, data-warehouse, business-intelligence, prediction

I am doing data mining using a data ware house. I have created dimension and fact tables and I inputted values for 2 years using a c# program. But when I follow the steps to mine the data in business intelligent studio, I am not getting any values suggestions when it shows the impact each value has in the variable I have chosen as predictable value. Please advice.

I am trying to use clustering, tree and neural n/ws. But none of them are giving any connections for the predictable value with the inputs. The table I tried has 5 foreign keys which are an integers, a primary key which is integer and a big int column and an int column. I want the algorithm top predict the int column using all other columns. Currently none of them are giving any associations with the predicting value.

Comment: If you query this data warehouse, do you get results?

Comment: yes, I have done basic queries and i am getting the results...Using usual DML queries though...Any idea?

Comment: You need to add more info: which mining algorithm are you using? with which parameters? how does your data look like?

Comment: @JotaBe edited the question. Please help